# guava com.google.common.net.InetAddresses

Tags: java, guava

I'd like to check in java if an IP address (IPv4, IPv6) is valid.

Google's guava library looks to me like a viable option. Its `isInetAddress(String ipString)` method works just fine for IPv4 addresses. However for IPv6 addresses I'd have to use the `isIsatapAddress(Inet6Address ip)` method.

The problem is that I want to use the `args` from the `void main(String []args)` to capture user's input and since the method requires a Inet6Address object I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: `InetAddresses.isInetAddress()` should work for both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. How does it not work and for what specific values?

Comment: And what this have to do with `sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil`?

Comment: Well, it seems it works as you say it. I was typing the IPc6 address and I must have made a mistake. Is there a function that accepts the address inkl the netmask like 2607:f0d0:1002:51::4/64 and not just 2607:f0d0:1002:51::4? Sorry, I didn't get it what you mean by saying And what this have to do with sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil

Comment: You could strip the netmask off with a little `indexOf` and `substring`, I don't think there's a method for that yet in Guava.

Comment: I wondered why the title of your question contained `sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil` which is then never mentioned again. If you considered using it, don't -- `sun.*` packages are implementation details of your JRE, not meant to be used and not available on all JREs.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, that was a stupid copy and paste mistake. Yes, I've read about and went for google's guava. Thank you Philipp

Comment: I've edited the title, so now it should be correct.

Comment: Much nicer title! I summarized my comments in an answer below and added a method that also accepts addresses with a netmask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`InetAddresses.isInetAddress(String)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.html#isInetAddress%28java.lang.String%29) should work for both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

If you have also want to accept something like `2607:f0d0:1002:51::4/64` you could strip the netmask off with a little indexOf and substring, I don't think there's a method for that yet in Guava:

```
static boolean isInetAddressOrBlock(String address) {
  int slash = address.lastIndexOf('/');
  if (slash != -1) {
    address = address.substring(0, slash);
  }
  return InetAddresses.isInetAddress(address);
}
```

If you considered using `sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil`, don't -- `sun.*` packages are implementation details of your JRE, not meant to be used and not available on all JREs.

Answer (score 0):

I agree about the InetAddresses.isInetAddress(String). It should do the job for validating both IPV4 and IPV6 addresses.

But, I want to share my experience with validation issue on IPV6 addresses which contains more than 4 characters and leading zeros.

For example, Let's say that i got the following Address:

```
1234:000002001:1234:0000:0000:C1C0:ABCD:0876
```

InetAddresses.isInetAddress return's valid address but in the other hand, it looks not a valid IPV6 address if I'm taking in consideration the textual representation in [RFC4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291)

Comment: After debugging the isInetAddress method in guava-15.0 sources, It looks to me like a bug. in textToNumericFormatV6 function they are parsing the hex into byte array and there's no problem here... "000002001" is a valid hex. What do you think ?

Comment: `1234:000002001:1234:...` is not a valid IP6 Address.